# php get post not working

Tags: php, post, get

I'm stuck on creating a system that collects both the user's first and second name. I've created two pages, htest1.php and htest2.php. htest1.php contains a form for the users to enter their details. The second page htest2.php has a script to find the data sent using the form and return this data to displayed in the first page.

For some reason it's not working and coming up with two input boxes when I execute in a browser.

Here is my code for htest1.php:

```
<?php
    if(isset($_GET['submit'])){
        echo "Hello".$_GET['fname'];
        echo "Hello".$_GET['sname'];

    }
?>

<form method="post" action= "htest2.php"
    <label for="firstname" Enter your name</label>
    <input type="text" id="firstname" name="firstname" />
    <input type="text" id="surname" name="surname" />
    <inout type="submit" id="submit" name="submit" value="Send" />
</form>
```

Code for htest2.php:

```
    <?php
$fname = $_POST['firstname'];
$sname = $_POST['surname'];
header ("Location: htest1.php?fname=$fname&sname=$sname");
    ?>
```

Can anyone spot the error(s)?

Comment: There's no error. Your second page redirects to the first which displays two input boxes. Your condition at the top of the first page never executes because you aren't sending a variable called `submit`.

Comment: `<?php
    { if(!empty($_REQUEST['fname']))
        echo "Hello".$_REQUEST['fname'];
       if(!empty($_REQUEST['sname']))
     echo "Hello".$_REQUEST['sname'];

    }
 
 
?>

<form method="post" action= "htest2.php">
  
    <input type="text" id="firstname" name="firstname" />
    <input type="text" id="surname" name="surname" />
    <input type="submit" id="submit" name="submit" value="Send" />
</form>
`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

when you redirect to first page again, $_GET['submit'] is not set. Try

```
<?php
    if(isset($_GET['fname']) && isset($_GET['lname'])){
        echo "Hello".$_GET['fname'];
        echo "Hello".$_GET['sname'];

    }
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You did not close the form and also your submit button and label having type errors ('inout'). Try this:

```
<form method="post" action="htest2.php">
  <label for="firstname">Enter your name</label>
  <input type="text" id="firstname" name="firstname" />
  <input type="text" id="surname" name="surname" />
  <input type="submit" id="submit" name="submit" value="Send" />
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no html tag called `<inout />`.
The form action is fine but a better approach would be to set the action attribute to `htest1.php` and the method to `post`. Also you forgot a `>` behind the action attribute.

```
<?php
    if(isset($_GET['submit'])){
        echo "Hello".$_GET['fname'];
        echo "Hello".$_GET['sname'];
    }
?>

<form method="get" action="htest1.php">
    <label for="firstname">Enter your name</label>
    <input type="text" id="firstname" name="firstname" />
    <input type="text" id="surname" name="surname" />
    <input type="submit" id="submit" name="submit" value="Send" />
</form>
```